# How simplify string of Indian districts in Java?

Tags: java, android, string

There is a string of (comma separated) Indian districts (may be all districts or may be not, its user's choice).
For example - `String districts = district1,district2,district3...`
This string is shown in a `TextView` by `.setText(districts)`.
Simply, all districts are shown comma separated in `TextView`

**The Problem is -**
If the string contains all Indian districts then it looks bad when they are shown in `TextView`.
The more districts 'districts' variable contains the more bad it will look in `TextView`

**What I expect -**
If this string contains all districts of any state(s) then only state name should be shown in place of all districts of it. It will reduce the size of string and will look much better.

**What I tried -**
If string contains all districts of India then `TextView` will show India in place of all districts

```
private String getSimplfiedDistrictsString(String districts){
    String finalString = "";
    if(districts.equals(allDistricts)){ // 'allDistricts' is a string which contains all Indian districts name ( comma separated )
        finalString = "Every district of India";
    }
    //Looking for function which simplify states name also
    //For example if district contain all district of Rajasthan state then in 'finalString' name of all districts should be replaced with only 'Rajasthan'
    //But if 'districts' variable contains some districts of any state but not all then they should remain as it is
    return finalString;
}
```

Hope you guys understood the problem and the expected result.

**Edit--------**

Assume, 
*district1,district2,district3 are Rajasthan's district* 
And 
*district4,district5 are Gujrat's districts*

***Case 1***
Input  = district1,district2,district3,district4 
Output = Rajasthan,district4

***Case 2***
Input  = district1,district2,district3,district4,district5 
Output = Rajasthan,Gujrat

Comment: You need to show sample input and output data here, preferably multiple examples.  We can't follow/help your question without this information.

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as that tag is for problems/questions related to the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic programming question and actually has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: Maybe convert the list into ArrayList with `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(districts.split(",")));` and use `containsAll` method?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Here are some cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

This update is an extension of the original solution and has been added to meet the requirement stated in the updated question.

In order to achieve the requirement mentioned in your updated question, you can extend the original solution as follows:

1. Create a `Map<String, Set<String>> mapStates` to store the states (`String`) as keys and their districts (`Set<String>`) as values. Also, create a `List<String> resultList` to store the states (`String`) whose all districts exist in `districtSetTextView`.
2. Iterate the `keySet` of `mapStates` and populate `resultList` with the states (`String`) whose all districts exist in `districtSetTextView`. Remove all districts of such states from `districtSetTextView`.
3. Add all the remaining elements of `districtSetTextView` to `resultList` and finally, return the `String` containing all the values of `resultList` joined on the comma.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> districtSetRajasthan = new HashSet<>();
        districtSetRajasthan.add("Dist1");
        districtSetRajasthan.add("Dist2");
        districtSetRajasthan.add("Dist3");

        Set<String> districtSetGujrat = new HashSet<>();
        districtSetGujrat.add("Dist4");
        districtSetGujrat.add("Dist5");

        Map<String, Set<String>> mapStates = new LinkedHashMap<String, Set<String>>();
        mapStates.put("Rajasthan", districtSetRajasthan);
        mapStates.put("Gujrat", districtSetGujrat);

        // Tests
        String textViewString = "Dist1,Dist2,Dist3,Dist4";
        System.out.println(getStateDistString(textViewString, mapStates));

        textViewString = "Dist1,Dist2,Dist3,Dist4,Dist5";
        System.out.println(getStateDistString(textViewString, mapStates));
    }

    static String getStateDistString(String districts, Map<String, Set<String>> mapStates) {
        // Split districts on comma and put the elements of the resultListing array into
        // a HashSet
        Set<String> districtSetTextView = Arrays.stream(districts.split(","))
                                                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String state : mapStates.keySet()) {
            Set<String> allDistrictsOfState = mapStates.get(state);
            if (districtSetTextView.containsAll(allDistrictsOfState)) {
                resultList.add(state);
                districtSetTextView.removeAll(allDistrictsOfState);
            }
        }

        // Add the remaining values of districtSetTextView to resultList
        resultList.addAll(districtSetTextView);

        return String.join(",", resultList);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Rajasthan,Dist4
Rajasthan,Gujrat
```

### Original answer:

Simply, store all the districts of each state into separate `HashSet<String>` i.e. for each state, you will have a `HashSet<String>` containing its districts.

Split the string of the TextView on comma and put the elements of the resulting array into a `HashSet<String>`. Finally,  check if this set contains all districts of the corresponding state by using [`Set#containsAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-).

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> districtSetRajasthan = new HashSet<>();
        districtSetRajasthan.add("Dist1");
        districtSetRajasthan.add("Dist2");
        districtSetRajasthan.add("Dist3");

        String textViewString = "Dist1,Dist2,Dist3";

        // Split the string of the TextView on comma and put the elements of the
        // resulting array into a HashSet
        Set<String> districtSetTextView = Arrays.stream(textViewString.split(","))
                                                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        // Check if districtSetTextView contains all districts of Rajasthan
        if (districtSetTextView.containsAll(districtSetRajasthan)) {
            System.out.println("Rajasthan");
        } else {
            System.out.println(textViewString);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Rajasthan
```

Comment: Can you please include either **case** I have shown in edit.

Comment: @GauravSaini - I have added an update to meet the requirements of your updated question. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Let me know if this fit in stack overflow policy or not -- I am expecting a bit more. For example the remaining district should be displayed as `Rajasthan, Gujrat(Dist4)` instead of `Rajasthan, Dist4`. Should I edit my question and mention the same requirement. Please tell what you think about it.

Comment: @GauravSaini - I recommend you post a separate question to keep this Q/A (and also the next one that you will post) focussed. In your new question, you can post the link (you can get the link by clicking `Share` below the answer) to this answer so that anyone who will attempt to answer your question can understand the context quickly.

Comment: Here it is, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65958903/13962262 . Hope you get it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could group districts using `Collectors.groupingBy` and then check the size of each state,

example:

```
Map<String, List<String>> allStates;  

String getSimplifiedDistrictsString(String districtsString) {
    // in this part you are grouping districts by their states
    // example:
    // allStates = {"s1": ["d1", "d2", "d3"], "s2": ["d4", "d5", "d6"]}
    // districtsString = "d1,d2,d3,d4"
    // states = {"s1": ["d1", "d2", "d3"], "s2": ["d4"]}
    Map<String, List<String>> states = Stream.of(districtsString.split(","))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> {
                // d - district name
                for (var e : allStates.entrySet()) {
                    // e.key() - state name
                    // e.value() - list of districts 
                    // if the state contains specific district then group by that state
                    if (e.getValue().contains(d)) {
                        return e.getKey();
                    }
                }
                throw new RuntimeException("State of district not found: " + d);
            }));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (var e : states.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getValue().containsAll(allStates.get(e.getKey()))) {
            sb.append(e.getKey()).append(","); // append name of a state
        } else {
            e.getValue().forEach(s -> sb.append(s).append(",")); // append names of all districts
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Trying to implement your code in my project until then you can elaborate your answer's upper part (above `StringBuilder`) using some comments. I will inform you shortly if it worked.

Comment: `e.getValue().forEach(s -> sb.append(s).append(","))` requires API>24 in android. But the current minimum is 16. If you have any suggestions on it? Let me know what you think about it.

Comment: You can just use string concatenation: `String output = ""; output += e.getKey() + ','; output += s + ',';`

Comment: Grouping throwing error, except this everything working fine (I checked by passing hardcoded map `states = {"s1": ["d1", "d2", "d3"], "s2": ["d4"]}`).