# How simplify string of Indian districts in Java? ( Problem Extended )

Tags: java, android, string

I have a string of India districts. For example `String districts = district1,district2,district3,...`so on (maybe all or some of districts of India). 
Assume, 
*district1,district2,district3 are Rajasthan's district* 
And 
*district4,district5,district6 are Gujrat's districts*


**What is scenario**
I want to show districts variable in `TextView` but if this string contains all districts of any state(s) then only state name should be shown in place of all districts of it. It will reduce the size of string and will look much better.
**[For detailed explanation refer to base question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65952176/13962262)**

***Achieved Case 1***
Input  = district1,district2,district3,district4 
Output = Rajasthan,district4

***Achieved Case 2***
Input  = district1,district2,district3,district4,district5 
Output = Rajasthan,district4,district5

***Achieved Case 2***
Input  = district1,district2,district3,district4,district5,district6 
Output = Rajasthan,Gujrat

**[Above cases achieved by @Live and Let Live answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65952389/13962262)**

***Expected Case 1***
Input  = district1,district2,district3,district4 
Output = Rajasthan, Gujrat (district4)

***Expected Case 2***
Input  = district1,district2,district3,district4,district5 
Output = Rajasthan,Gujrat (district4,district5)

***Expected Case 3***
Input  = district1,district2,district3,district4,district5,district6 
Output = Rajasthan,Gujrat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending on [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65952176/how-simplify-string-of-indian-districts-in-java/65952389#65952389), given below is how you can achieve this requirement:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> districtSetRajasthan = new HashSet<>();
        districtSetRajasthan.add("Dist1");
        districtSetRajasthan.add("Dist2");
        districtSetRajasthan.add("Dist3");

        Set<String> districtSetGujrat = new HashSet<>();
        districtSetGujrat.add("Dist4");
        districtSetGujrat.add("Dist5");

        Map<String, Set<String>> mapStates = new LinkedHashMap<String, Set<String>>();
        mapStates.put("Rajasthan", districtSetRajasthan);
        mapStates.put("Gujrat", districtSetGujrat);

        // Tests
        String textViewString = "Dist1,Dist2,Dist3,Dist4";
        System.out.println(getStateDistString(textViewString, mapStates));

        textViewString = "Dist1,Dist2,Dist3,Dist4,Dist5";
        System.out.println(getStateDistString(textViewString, mapStates));
    }

    static String getStateDistString(String districts, Map<String, Set<String>> mapStates) {
        // Split districts on comma and put the elements of the resultListing array into
        // a HashSet
        Set<String> districtSetTextView = Arrays.stream(districts.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String state : mapStates.keySet()) {
            Set<String> allDistrictsOfState = mapStates.get(state);
            if (districtSetTextView.containsAll(allDistrictsOfState)) {
                resultList.add(state);
                districtSetTextView.removeAll(allDistrictsOfState);
            } else {
                List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String dist : districtSetTextView) {
                    if (allDistrictsOfState.contains(dist)) {
                        temp.add(dist);
                    }
                }
                if (temp.size() > 0) {
                    String x = state + "(" + String.join(",", temp) + ")";
                    resultList.add(x);
                    districtSetTextView.removeAll(temp);
                }
            }
        }

        return String.join(",", resultList);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Rajasthan,Gujrat(Dist4)
Rajasthan,Gujrat
```

### What's new in this solution:

1. Create a temporary `List<String> temp` to store the districts of a state if the full set of districts is not present in `textViewString`.
2. Create a string as state + "(" + strings of `temp` joined on comma + ")" and add the same to `resultList`. Like the original solution, remove all districts of `temp` from `districtSetTextView`.